# Unique constraint JayData

Tags: javascript, unique-constraint, jaydata

Is there a way to specify that a field has to be unique with JayData (same as SQL)?

For example:

```
$data.Entity.extend("Test", {
    Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
    Name: { type: "string", required: true, unique: true, maxLength: 200 }
});
```

If the keyword doesn't exist, how to do it? Actually, I don't want an element to be added if it already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need autogenerated id field then declare name as key and computed false so it will be a unique field.
If you want to keep the id field then you can use a unique index to achieve what you want.
Index support is in the pro providers.

Comment: Okay maybe I can try to do without the id field. However I don't understand your second solution. What do you mean by `unique index`? Could you provide an example? Thanks

Comment: We published a blog post about it yesterday. jaydata.org/blog

Comment: I think a professional version is not worth for my app. I will remove the index field. Too bad... Thanks anyway.